# Moodle SQL to update particular record in database not working

Tags: php, sql, database, moodle

I have a form where the user can add courses and when the user clicks on the edit button he is redirected to another page so as to modify the data in the form. But when the user clicks on the Save button, nothing happens. A blank page appears. In the normal situation, "successful" needs to appear on the page.

Codes which handles the update query:

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/config.php');

global $DB;

$id = required_param('facid', PARAM_TEXT);
$name = required_param('name', PARAM_TEXT);
$course_detail = required_param('course_detail', PARAM_TEXT);
$course_outline = required_param('course_outline', PARAM_TEXT);
$course_obj = required_param('course_obj', PARAM_TEXT);
//$programme = required_param('programme', PARAM_TEXT);

$update = $DB->execute_sql("UPDATE {courses} SET name = '$name' AND course_detail = '$course_detail' WHERE id = '$id'");

if(!$update)
{
    echo "Could not update";
}

else
{
    echo "Successful";
}

?>
```

I can understand that the SQL statement is wrong but i can't seem to fix it as it is quite different from the PHP codes I've learned. I also tried checking on this [link](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API) but can't seem to find the answer. I'm new to Moodle.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

I know its late but might help some one in future so posting the answer,

As per Moodle  [docs](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Updating_records) below is the code to update the record while $dataobjec is the associative array. $dataobject must have an id field in order to update the record

```
$DB->update_record($table, $dataobject, $bulk=false)

 $dataobject= array(
   'id'             => $_POST['id'],
    'value2'        => $_POST['value2'],
    'value2'        => $_POST['value3']
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I could finally solve it so i thought of posting the answer for future new Moodle developers.

**Codes:**

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/config.php');

global $DB;

$id = required_param('facid', PARAM_TEXT);
$name = required_param('name', PARAM_TEXT);
$course_detail = required_param('course_detail', PARAM_TEXT);
$course_outline = required_param('course_outline', PARAM_TEXT);
$course_obj = required_param('course_obj', PARAM_TEXT);
//$programme = required_param('programme', PARAM_TEXT);

$record = new stdclass;
$record->id = $id;
$record->name = $name;
$record->course_detail = $course_detail;
$record->course_outline = $course_outline;
$record->course_obj = $course_obj;


$sql = $DB->update_record('courses', $record); 


if(!$sql)
{
    echo "Could not update";
}

else
{
    echo "Successful";
}

?>
```